# how to get data from WCF using javascript and html in Win8 Metro App？

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Who can tell me how to get data from WCF using javascript and html in Win8 Metro App? If
it's impossible with wcf, how can I get data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of information on the MSDN site. There are some good blogs that give examples and speaks to this. Try starting here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/09/22/wcf-in-win8-metro-styled-apps-absolutely-supported.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/